# Revert list to previous order after prependTo using Jquery

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I have a list which shows only four (featured) list items initially, and once a 'show more' button is clicked, it reveals the remainder of the list. I use`$('.featured').prependTo('.feature-list');` to display the featured items first. However, when I click the 'show more' button, I want the list to be displayed in the  original order before the prependTo happened. I can't seem to figure out how to do this.

```js
$('.featured').prependTo('.feature-list');

$('.feature-list').find('li:gt(3)').hide();
$('.more-btn').click(function() {
    $('.feature-list li:gt(3)').show();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p>List 1</p>
<ul class="feature-list feature-p-list1">
  <li>Item 1</li>
  <li class="featured">Item 2</li>
  <li>Item 3</li>
  <li>Item 4</li>
  <li class="featured">Item 5</li>
  <li>Item 6</li>
  <li>Item 7</li>
  <li class="featured">Item 8</li>
  <li class="featured">Item 9</li>
  <li>Item 10</li>
</ul>
<button class="more-btn">Show More</button>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just try hide and show using `:not()` filter

https://api.jquery.com/not-selector/

```js
$('.feature-list > li:not(.featured)').hide()

$('.more-btn').click(function() {
  $('.feature-list > li:not(.featured)').show()
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p>List 1</p>
<ul class="feature-list feature-p-list1">
  <li>Item 1</li>
  <li class="featured"><b>Item 2</b></li>
  <li>Item 3</li>
  <li>Item 4</li>
  <li class="featured">Item 5</li>
  <li>Item 6</li>
  <li>Item 7</li>
  <li class="featured">Item 8</li>
  <li class="featured">Item 9</li>
  <li>Item 10</li>
</ul>
<button class="more-btn">Show More</button>
```

Comment: Thanks for the  quick reply. However, what if there were tags in the list item, for example, if <li class="featured"><b>List  2</b></li>, then such items are not shown, despite having the class "featured". Anyway to overcome this?

Comment: @user1038814 Not a big deal. check updated answer